# How to find the minimum pixel value within a region of interest?

Tags: python, arcpy, remote-sensing, dark-object-subtraction

I am working on a Python script for dark object subtraction, a radiometric correction method for remotely sensed data.To accomplish this, I need to find the minimum band pixel value of a waterbody within a region of interest (ROI) (screenshot).  My initial thought was to create a polygon within a Landsat scene and use Zonal Statistics as Table to find the minimum value.  However, I cannot easily call this minimum value later on in the script.  Another thought was to convert the band to a numpy array and find the min value (excluding 0), although I am uncertain how to subset the array to my ROI.  How can I find the minimum value using a region of interest so that I can easily call this value later on in the script?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to answer I gave to a similar question ([determine min and max elevation ... within my current extent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107460/using-arcpy-how-can-i-determine-min-and-max-elevation-from-a-raster-dem-layer-w)), I wonder if this would work:

```
import arcpy

# this sets extent to current display, you can instead set it to ROI polygon
arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument.activeView.Extent

# for a multi-band raster, pay attention to the band index (last input)
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management("c:/temp/raster.tif", "rlayer", "#", arcpy.env.extent, "1")

# Get the geoprocessing result object
bandMinResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("rlayer", "MINIMUM")
# Get the elevation minimum value from geoprocessing result object
bandMinDN = elevMinResult.getOutput(0)
```

Comment: Great, this is an excellent solution.  Thanks Erica.

Comment: Glad to know it works!

Answer (score 2):

You could still use zonal statistics with the minimum option.  It produces a raster would could be used for further processing  [Zonal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w7000000)