# Python script for dark object subtraction on Landsat 8 Imagery

Tags: python, remote-sensing, landsat, landsat-8, dark-object-subtraction

Does anyone know of any python scripts that will allow me to conduct such a process? I am limited to open source software and have minor experience in Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the minimum pixel value within a region of interest?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107734/how-to-find-the-minimum-pixel-value-within-a-region-of-interest)

Comment: Have you looked at the DOS function in the R "landsat" package? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/landsat/landsat.pdf

Comment: @MarkC I think this question is unique in that the OP is asking for the process involved in performing DOS.  The question you refer to is interested in a smaller component of DOS (i.e. finding the minimum value in an AOI).

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thanks your reply. I have yes but wasn't sure whether the R "landsat" package supported landsat 8 imagery? Also, I am keen to explore python.  After atmospheric correction I am processing the imagery using a combination of R and QGIS.

Comment: I do not believe that Sarah Goslee has updated the landsat package since 2012, so it would not directly support landsat 8. However, the at-sensor reflectance correction is fairly straightforward for landsat 8 and on top of that the DOS equation is extremely simple. If would be trivial to download the source code and modify it accordingly.

Comment: Also, I believe that you want the "radiocorr" function. The DOS function is to provide calibration values for DOS and not an actual output image.

Comment: R Landsat package can't handle Landsat 8 imagery. You could try QGIS [semi automatic classification plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/) and apply the implemented DOS1 correction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as a starting point: http://www.machinalis.com/blog/python-for-geospatial-data-processing/

Instead of classifying you want to do another process, but there are common basics there...

Comment: This link does not exist anymore

Comment: @HasneinTareque you are right. If you contact the guys at Machinalis (FB, Twitter, info@machinalis.com) about it they send you the contents of the blog post by email.

Comment: The mentioned blog-post is here: https://www.web.archive.org/web/20171101235934/http://www.machinalis.com/blog/python-for-geospatial-data-processing/

Comment: I contacted the guys at Mchinalis as you suggested, but finding and putting it back here makes your answer useful again. Thanks.